# New Task.WaitAsync(CancellationToken) API and exceptions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I'm trying to use the new .NET 6 [`Task.WaitAsync(CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync) API.
What I'd like to accomplish is to cancel the waiting for a task, while still being capable of trying to cancel the task itself (it calls an async library and I cannot be sure it will observe the `cancellationToken` I passed in, or at least not in a timely manner) and avoid to swallow any possible exception it could throw.

So, for example, let's say I want to call an async method:

```
private async Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    //do something before the call

    await Library.DoSomethingAsync(cancellationToken); // Let's pretend
        // this is a call to a libary that accepts a cancellationToken,
        // but I cannot be 100% sure it will be observed
}
```

from a button click event handler:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var tsk = DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token);
    try
    {
        await tsk.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) when (ex is OperationCanceledException)
    {
        tsk.Forget();
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure the await will last 5 seconds max, but when the `OperationCanceledException` is caught the task could still be running and I don't want to swallow any of the exceptions that it could throw.
So what can I do now if I don't want to await it?

I thought using a `FireAndForget` extension method like this inside the catch block:

```
public static async void Forget(this Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is this an acceptable pattern, or should I just trust the library and hope it will sooner or later be canceled anyway?
And what if it will never do so, will the `Forget` method await forever?

Comment: `try`/`catch (Exception)` is a terrible pattern regardless of tasks or not.

Comment: *"I don't want to swallow any of the exceptions that it could throw."* <== What do you want to happen if the `tsk` throws an exception (not an `OperationCanceledException`) after the completion of the `WaitAsync`? Do you want to silently log the error, or loudly inform the user with a popup or something, at a point in time that they have probably forgot that button click and they are doing other things?

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, you're right, but is it still so terrible even when it's not used to just swallow all the exceptions? Here I was only trying to rethrow every possible exception, how else could that be done avoiding to write `catch (Exception)`?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That's a really good point, maybe it depends on the semantic of the application. Anyway I wasn't trying to just log or inform the user, what I really wanted was to make the exception escalate using the standard .net policy, which, by the way, is what it seems to be doing, that's the whole point of the throw inside the catch block of the Forget method. But after reading your comment I think that it could be even worse, I mean to have a sudden crash when "they have probably forgot that button click and they are doing other things"...

Comment: You've shown us the `Forget` extension method, but you haven't shown how you intend to use it. Could you include in the question an example of intended usage? Btw the try-catch-throw pattern is superfluous. You'll get the exact same behavior by just awaiting the `task`.

Comment: IMHO your question should be clear and specific about what behavior is desirable. Currently, by asking *"is this an acceptable pattern?"*, is like asking us to tell you what should be correct behavior of your app. Which is opinion-based to say the least.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Oh, I'm sorry, my bad...I forgot to call the Forget extension method, it was meant to be called in the catch block of the button click handler (I've edited the post).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias " Btw the try-catch-throw pattern is superfluous. You'll get the exact same behavior by just awaiting the task". Yes, but I don't want to await it. I wanna get out of the catch block of the button click handler and do something else there after that, while the Forget extension method is awaiting for the task to complete or rethrowing any of its exceptions.

Comment: I am talking about the `Forget` extension method. Do you think that your current implementation is any different than this? `public static async void Forget(this Task task) => await task;`

Comment: You could take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void "Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming - Avoid Async Void") article, to get a more in-depth understanding of the error handling semantics of `async void` methods.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias `public static async void Forget(this Task task) => await task;` Ah, ok, thank you, I see it now, it's really better this way (btw my implementation came from here https://github.com/brminnick/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/blob/main/Src/AsyncAwaitBestPractices/SafeFireAndForgetExtensions.shared.cs but here the try-catch-throw pattern was meant to use the parameters passed to the method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the `WaitAsync` and `Forget` functionality in a single extension method like the one below:

```
public async static Task WaitAsyncAndThenOnErrorCrash(this Task task,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task waitTask = task.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
    try { await waitTask; }
    catch when (waitTask.IsCanceled) { OnErrorCrash(task); throw; }

    static async void OnErrorCrash(Task task)
    {
        try { await task.ConfigureAwait(false); }
        catch when (task.IsCanceled) { } // Ignore overdue cancellation
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    try
    {
        await DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token).WaitAsyncAndThenOnErrorCrash(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { } // Ignore
}
```

In case the `DoSomethingAsync` completes with error either before or after the cancellation, the application will crash with a popup saying *"Unhandled exception has occurred in your application"*. The user will have the option to continue running the app, by clicking the "Continue" button:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, that was really informative. 
Just as a side note, I'm not receiveing this dialog window cause I'm using `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException);`, cause I prefer not to leave the user the choice to continue with an applicaton that could be in a pretty messed up state.

Comment: @Oaraisi this can be a wise choice, depending on the type of the application. It might not be ideal for example in case of an application where the user might lose a lot of work, if they are not given the option to save their work (or attempt to save it at least).